# Checkbox without style in a second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using a combination of JSF + Bootstrap + jQuery DataTables a boring problem:

I'm using a plugin called iCheck to stylize my checkbox, see the javascript:

```
function initIcheckbox(){
    //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
    $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
    });
    $(".iCheck-helper").remove();

}
```

Here is where I invoke `initCheckBox`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initSummerNote();
    initDataTable(false);
    initIcheckbox();
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(handleAjaxEvents);
});
```

In the first page of datatable jquery every checkbox is stylized as i hope and generate this html code:

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal-blue" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input id="j_idt41:example1:7:j_idt54" type="checkbox" name="j_idt41:example1:7:j_idt54" class="minimal" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','@this','@this')" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"></div>
```

WHen i change to second page the checkbox aren't stylized, look the html generated in second page:

```
<input id="j_idt41:example1:10:j_idt54" type="checkbox" name="j_idt41:example1:10:j_idt54" class="minimal" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','@this','@this')">
```

As you can see the "div" around input isn't created, I don't know why.

If I change to second page and refresh the page then checkbox style works, I noted that just page I'm seeing is stylized.

Comment: Where do you invoke `initIcheckbox()`?

Comment: I edited the post with the peace of code when i invoke the initIcheckBox

Comment: I supposed it is in `$(document).ready()`. If your page loads dynamically, elements are created after  `$(document).ready()` so the styles aren't applied (script doesn't apply for them).

Comment: how can i solve that ?

Comment: It will be easier if you post more code, like datatable structure. If you say that you refresh page and see new styles then you have to also somehow save this state.

Comment: Yeah i'm saving the state of datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

jQuery DataTables removes non-visible elements from DOM. That is why when you run `initIcheckbox()` it only affects first page elements.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to define a function that will be called when table is drawn.

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   "drawCallback": function(settings){   
      //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
      $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
         checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
         radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
      });
   }
});
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.